# Embedded Browser in the background for crawling JAVA

Tags: java, browser

I am looking for a web browser that would run in background in my java application. It would fetch all resources related to a url and create the DOM, run starting js scripts and etc. It would do everything a browser does but it need not have a UI but an API to control the rendered page, execute js scripts and etc on it is needed.
It should support latest HTML, CSS and JS implementations.

Is there something like that out there?

Answer (score 1):

It is easily possible using products like **phantom.js**. The reason that it can be done easily in phantom.js and not in java is - phantom.js uses V8 scripting engine, the same engine that empowers Google Chrome browser. So effectively Phantom JS is like an invisible google chrome browser. There's no similar support available in Java.

Java does support custom scripting engine [Scripting Engine in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/). But that is just one part of the story, you need to be able to load HTML/DOM, interpret CSS etc.

So , my suggestion will be to call phantom.js from your  java app. You can explore using JNI to manipulate phantom.js behavior.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Sorry, can't upvote you. Not enough "reputation" yet.

Comment: "There's no similar support available in Java." - well, I guess there is com.sun.webpane.webkit.